# Proving $\forall x (\exists Y ((Dx \to Yx) \land (Yx \to Ax))) \vdash \forall x (Dx \to Ax)$

Tags: logic, second-order-logic

I'm trying to prove the following:
$$\forall x (\exists Y ((Dx \to Yx) \land (Yx \to Ax))) \vdash \forall x (Dx \to Ax)$$

The following is my first attempt. However, I'm not sure if I can just drop the existential quantifier when it is nested.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \begin{array}{l}\forall x (\exists Y ((Dx \to Yx) \land (Yx \to Ax)) \end{array} \\
2 & \begin{array}{ll}\forall x ((Dx \to Dx) \land (Dx \to Ax)) \end{array} \\
3 & \begin{array}{lll}\forall x (Dx \to Ax)\end{array} \\
\end{array}$$

The reasoning seems valid to me. Let's say that each time an organism *x* is damaged, *Dx*, it shows avoidance behavior, *Ax*. We introduce the concept of 'pain' as a factor responsible for triggering the avoidance behavior, *Yx*. So, each time an *x* is damaged, there's such a thing as the feeling of pain that triggers the avoidance behavior. Since the domain contains only *D* and *A*, that feeling of pain can be identified as either *D* or *A* (we don't assume any semantics related to *Y*) and simply eliminate the existential quantifier. Evidently, *Y* just plays a role of a mediator.

How to improve the proof?

Comment: You use the tag "first-order logic", but you are quantifying a predicate ($Y$).

Comment: Dropping an existential *inside* a larger statement is never a good idea ... you'll first need to drop the universal.  How exactly to do all that depends on the exact nature of the inference rules of the particular formal proof system you are using though ... and there are many, many variants on those. So, you'll need to take a close look at those rules .. and if you want our help, you'll need to specify those rules in your post. And please don't say 'Existential Elimniation', 'Universal Introduction', etc. because those are still defined differently between different systems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you get from step $1$ to step $2$. This need more developpement. eg you can rewrite $Dx \longrightarrow Yx \equiv \neg Dx \vee Yx$ and $Yx \longrightarrow Ax \equiv \neg Yx \vee Ax$ and use De Morgan's laws from here.

**handling the existential quantifier :**
I suggest to handle $Y$ semantically. Say we have a model $\mathcal{M}$ with universe $M$ that satisfies$$\mathcal{M} \models \forall x (\exists Y ((Dx \to Yx) \land (Yx \to Ax)))$$

> We need to show that for any $m \in M$, $(\mathcal{M}, x^{\mathcal{M}} = m) \models Dx \longrightarrow Ax$
> (ie $\mathcal{M}\models Dm \longrightarrow Am$, we'll write directly $(\mathcal{M}, x^{\mathcal{M}} = m) \models Dm \longrightarrow Am$ to stress out the substitutions).

Let $m \in M$. Since $(\mathcal{M}, x^{\mathcal{M}} = m) \models \exists Y \big( (Dm \to Ym) \wedge (Ym \to Am) \big)$, there exist a set $S \subseteq M$ such that :
$$(\mathcal{M}, x^{\mathcal{M}} = m, Y^{\mathcal{M}} = S) \models (Dm \to Sm) \wedge (Sm \to Am)$$
whence $(\mathcal{M}, x^{\mathcal{M}} = m, Y^{\mathcal{M}} = S) \models (Dm \to Am)$ and finally :
$$(\mathcal{M}, x^{\mathcal{M}} = m) \models Dm \to Am$$ QED.

Hence, $\mathcal{M} \models \forall x \ (Dx \longrightarrow Ax)$

Comment: Thank you, Olivier. Perhaps my original question wasn't clear enough, so let me explain. I guess there're multiple ways of proving the statement. The statement is an instance of transitivity, so one way of proving would be to apply modus ponens two times as explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280893/how-do-i-prove-the-transitivity-of-a-set-of-implications

My problem, however, is that I'm not sure whether I can simply drop the existential quantifier and stop worrying about it. Or is it somehow prohibited (since the existential quantifier is nested)?